# Filter on Close Vote Review doesn't seem to be working across close reasons

Tags: bug, review, close-reasons

I went over to the [review queue on Super User](https://superuser.com/review/), filtered by "unclear what you're asking".

Instead I got to [review a question](https://superuser.com/review/close/231948) voted as duplicate. With 2 votes only on duplicate.

[image]

I thought it was a one-off thing, but the next one it pulled up one for Too broad.

[image]

Just to make things clear -

- these weren't audit reviews
- there weren't any flag votes from users who don't have 3k rep with flag close reason being other than what's selected as filter(ex: the duplicate/too broad posts didn't have "unclear what you're asking" flags so as to be picked in the review queue - I'm a Community Moderator at Super User so I can see the flags being applied on a post)

Comment: for the sake of completeness - there were no _expired_ close votes on the questions either, correct?

Comment: @gnat yes, that is correct

Comment: I had this issue, just refreshed the page and seemly went away.